# fread() blank.lines.skips leaves NA line

Tags: r, fread, read.csv

I have blank lines between monthly blocks of data in a csv file. I looked at using the `blank.line.skips = TRUE` parameter of fread or read.csv to drop those empty rows.

But what I am getting is a line with a NA at the end. *Why is the row not completely dropped?*

I did see some old data answers on SO about fread crashing when it has a blank row but that seems to have been fixed.

**TEST CASE**

```
temp <- data.table(a = c("a","","c","d"), 
                   b = c(10,"",30,40))

fwrite (temp, "test.csv")



mydata <- fread("test.csv", 
                blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**RESULTS**

I get the second row which is blank included with an NA added:

```
> mydata
a  b
1: a 10
2:   NA
3: c 30
4: d 40
```

I wanted (and expected):

```
> mydata
a  b
1: a 10
2: c 30
3: d 40
```

(I realise I can get this with a `mydata[complete.cases(mydata), ]` but I expected the `blank.lines.skips` to do this. From fread help "If TRUE blank lines in the input are ignored.")

Is this `fread` leaving the line a bug or feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform `fwrite (temp, "test.csv")` the second line (without considering headers) is not blank... It has a separator:

```
a,b
a,10
,
c,30
d,40
```

The argument `blank.lines.skips` is for truly blanklines:

Ex: with test.csv as following

```
a,b
a,10

c,30
d,40
```

To control :

```
> dim(fread("test.csv", blank.lines.skip = TRUE))
[1] 3 2
```

Argument `blank.lines.skip = TRUE` avoid stopping at the first blank line. Without setting this argument you would have:

```
> dim(fread("test.csv"))
[1] 1 2
Warning message:
In fread("test.csv") :
  Stopped reading at empty line 3 but text exists afterwards (discarded): c,30
```

### Edit:

To solve your problem of blank lines, I would advise to:

- Strip them from your file before reading your data if you have a lot of those lines.
- Drop them after reading if you have just a few of them.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. So do you recommend I strip the rows out of the input file and/or is there a neater way than my load then do complete cases?

Comment: Depends, if you have a lot of those, consider striping the file before. In the other case just drop them after reading.